# Why does ListView JSP tag serialize entire data object?

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

The ListViewTag class serialises the entire data object, even if those fields aren't used in the ListView.  I'm using a Hibernate entity which uses a list of objects from a many-to-many relationship and I only want to retrieve these when I need them.  When the Serializer class tries to serialise the  object then Hibernate tries to populate the list but it can't because there is no database session open.

Is there any way fields can be ignored by the com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer?

See stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.syngenta.combichem.model.CcwEnumeration.buildingBlocks, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serializeIterable(Serializer.java:171)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:109)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serializeMap(Serializer.java:158)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:121)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serializeIterable(Serializer.java:174)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:109)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serializeMap(Serializer.java:158)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:113)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serializeMap(Serializer.java:158)
    com.kendoui.taglib.json.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:111)
    com.kendoui.taglib.WidgetTag.script(WidgetTag.java:101)
    com.kendoui.taglib.WidgetTag.doEndTag(WidgetTag.java:61)
    com.kendoui.taglib.ListViewTag.doEndTag(ListViewTag.java:82)
```

Comment: this functionality is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Serializer class does not afford such functionality of skipping properties. You can check the source code which serialises at:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/a2c7ec547302c4741103f1f1bb034b57eb201f45/wrappers/java/kendo-taglib/src/main/java/com/kendoui/taglib/json/Serializer.java#L97

One way to go around this could be to create a ViewModel (or in your case a couple of ViewModels) which includes the required properties only.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Create a class which contains all the properties nececary for the field

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).